# PHP Date for mysql Date

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a column of type date (only date) in mysql. However, when I am using the following:

```
$Answer->dateCreated=date('d-m-y');
```

I'm getting an error

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

Any idea??

Comment: without seeing your object code its any ones guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did this and it is working:

```
$Answer->dateCreated = strtotime("now");
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQL's date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`, which in PHP would be `date('Y-m-d')`. Your format string is reversed and using 2 digit years instead of 4 - Y2k's old news by now... don't use 2 digit years anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
define('MYSQL_DATE_FORMAT', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
$Answer->dateCreated = date(MYSQL_DATE_FORMAT);
```

I understand you're not wishing to save the time, don't worry MySQL will ignore the time for these columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$Answer->dateCreated=date('Y-m-d');`